# Terser, tidier way to say you'd like "no further progression of [someone's] macular degeneration"

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm editing a church prayer sheet, and one of the requests is that someone's specific eye disorder won't keep getting worse. The original phrasing, unfortunately, was pretty awful: "Pray for Macular Degeneration to be maintained from further degeneration". I couldn't let that stand, and came up with "No further progression of macular degeneration" (with "pray for" implied, of course), but I'm not real happy with that either; it's too sesquipedalianly loquacious, and still a bit long too. I would say something about stasis, but that doesn't sound right for diseases.

The ideal here would be a nice short phrase/word, much like cancer's "remission", that applies to health problems that aren't generally recovered from but might not deteriorate further.

Comment: *arrest:* "... administration of high doses of antioxidants, fatty acids, carotenoids, amino acids, and minerals ... can dramatically enhance nutrient delivery and **arrest (further) degeneration** of vision." The Center for Natural & Integrative Medicine  
http://www.drkalidas.com/pathways/intravenous.html See also: *Macular Degeneration, Cataracts, and Retinopathy* DaSilva Institute, Florida http://www.dasilvainstitute.com/ocular-disorders

Comment: @Kris: Possibly. A bit too jargon-y in this context though; words like "remission" get a pass because of how common they are.

Comment: "remission" and similar terms are strictly defined in medical dictionaries, their "popular" use is mostly incorrect and considered ignorant usage. "A remission is a temporary end to the medical signs and symptoms of an incurable disease." Wikipedia en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cure  So watch out.

Comment: @Kris: Duly noted and already aware of that, otherwise I might have tried remission, which would not actually work here.

Comment: @NathanTuggy- This is a bit off topic but, why are you limiting God? Why wouldn't you just ask the congregation to pray for the petitioner's eyesight to be restored?

Comment: @Oldbag: A fair question; if that goes in, it will probably be in addition to this requested phrase, although they are asking for "healing" in general as well, so there's that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for some form of **[stabilize](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/stabilize)**, frequently used in medical contexts for exactly this meaning.

Comment: Although I suppose you could achieve what you want even more tersely by using your original phrasing and just dropping the "progression of" part. "No further macular degeneration" seems short and to the point.

Comment: Wow. Now I feel just a bit like a dunce. Your comment suggestion is extremely good.

Answer (score 0):

You are praying that the condition **does not get/become any worse** or that it **might not worsen.**

In fact, I see you actually used that in your question here.

Comment: Right, but how would you work that into a standalone semi-fragment? Something like "That her macular degeneration not worsen"? I guess that could be worse, but it's a bit wordy still.

Comment: Yes. Just like that. I think the problem with "wordiness" is "macular degeneration", not "worsen".